# Problem with friction

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, friction, free-body-diagram

Consider a block on a table which is placed on a frictionless surface (friction exists between table and block). When we push the block, why does the table move? What are the forces on the table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The table exerts a horizontal force on the block (friction).  By Newton's third law, the block exerts an equal and opposite horizontal force on the table.  This is the only horizontal force on table (the table is on frictionless surface), so the table moves horizontally in the direction in which you push on the block.

For the sake of completeness, there are also vertical forces on the table (gravity, normal force) but they balance out so the table doesn't move up or down.

Comment: @shaihorowitz, good point.  I have updated my answer.